# Why do I get "does not name a type" when compiling my hello world c++ file

Tags: c++, linux, compilation

After updating my Arch Linux system on my laptop, I ran into a lot of compilation errors when trying to compile the project I am working on. The same code compiles well on other machines.

So, I tried a little hello world program, and it fails with the same error.

I have spent quite some time trying to figure out what is happening, but I get nowhere, so I would very much appreciate any hints.

The file I try to compile is very simple:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it like this:

```
 $ g++ -Wall -Wfatal-errors hello.cpp -o hello
```

And get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8.2.1/memory:74,
             from /usr/local/include/format.h:36,
             from /usr/local/include/time.h:11,
             from /usr/include/pthread.h:24,
             from /usr/include/c++/8.2.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
             from /usr/include/c++/8.2.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/gthr.h:148,
             from /usr/include/c++/8.2.1/ext/atomicity.h:35,
             from /usr/include/c++/8.2.1/bits/ios_base.h:39,
             from /usr/include/c++/8.2.1/ios:42,
             from /usr/include/c++/8.2.1/ostream:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/8.2.1/iostream:39,
             from hello.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/8.2.1/ext/concurrence.h:124:5: error: 
'__gthread_mutex_t' does not name a type; did you mean 
'__pthread_mutex_s'?
 __gthread_mutex_t _M_mutex;
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 __pthread_mutex_s
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors
```

If I remove the `-Wfatal-errors` switch, I just get tons of more errors.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code shown, with or without the `-std` switch, so either the compiler's STL is buggy, or the compiler is misconfigured, or the installation is corrupted.

Comment: I will try to reinstall gcc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the two header files in /usr/local/include, i.e. format.h and time.h that was the cause of my problems. After removing them I am now able to compile my project again.